# PHP почему PhpStorm не находит метод real_escape_string?

Tags: php

```
 <?php

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $isbn = get_post($conn, 'isbn');
    $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "Сбой при удалении данных: $query<br>" .
        $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}

if (isset($_POST['author']) &&
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
    isset($_POST['isbn']))

{
    $author = get_post($conn, 'author');
    $title = get_post($conn, 'title');
    $category = get_post($conn, 'category');
    $year = get_post($conn, 'year');
    $isbn = get_post($conn,'isbn');
    $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
        "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) echo "Сбой при вставке данных: $query<br>" .
        $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}

echo <<<_END
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
<pre>
  Author   <input type="text" name="author">
  Title    <input type="text" name="title">
  Category <input type="text" name="category">
  Year     <input type="text" name="year">
  ISBN     <input type="text" name="isbn"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Добавить запись">
</pre>
</form>
_END;

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

if (!$result) die ("Сбой при доступе к базе данных: " . $conn->error);
   $rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)

{
        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        echo <<<_END

```
        Author $row[0]
        Title $row[1]
        Category $row[2]
        Year $row[3]
        ISBN $row[4]
```

_END;
    }

// кнопка
// УДАЛИТЬ ЗАПИСЬ
    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

```
function get_post($conn, $var)
{
    return $conn-> real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
```

Вот скрипт с кодом, метод который находится на 2 строчки выше - real_escape_string, почему -то не находится. В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Пользуйтесь  PDO.Блин че вы так его боитесь

Comment: Пользуйтесь лучше подготовленными выражениями, а не вот этим вот.

Comment: чего говорит то? вообще код не выполняется, или phpStorm его не знает и подсказки не выводит? о чем речь?

Comment: если подсказок нет, дак он там не телепат, чтобы угадать что за параметр `$conn` приходит в функцию, дабы предложить вам варианты методов. Хотите чтобы подсказки были, явно укажите класс переменной `$conn` в функции

Comment: вы индексировали по новой проект? укажите явный тип или phpdoc

Comment: real_escape_string - имеется в виду mysqli_real_escape_string ?

Comment: teran - код выполняется, и всё работает, но phpstorm пишет -  method 'real_escape_string' не найден

Comment: mydls - как по новой индексировать проект ?